# одиночная работа в git с имитацией команды

Tags: git, github

как, работая в одиночку над проектом, сымитировать командную разработку на git?
p.s. никогда не работал в команде, а подготовиться к такой работе надо

Comment: проект склонировать в две разные папки (или на два различных компа). Дальше сделать изменения на одной машине и на другой. закомитить. Потом на одной запушить, а на другой пройти через pull-push/

Comment: @KoVadim может выдумать несколько ролей, типа: manager, frontender, backender и от лица каждой из них плодить ветки и осуществлять действия?

Comment: Вообще то менеджеру (если только это не programm manager) нечего делать в гите. Но если Вам нравятся ролевые игры - вперед.

Comment: @KoVadim ну, не manager, а teamlead (progmanager)  - кто-то всех проверяющий + нужны же несколько виртуальных разработчиков

Comment: Самое главное - уметь пилить параллельно несколько фич в разных ветках, а потом ветки сливать в develop, а develop в master, остальное уже детали. Это и при разработке в одиночку не будет лишним

Comment: а разработчик в команде может самостоятельно посмотреть каков результат его работы непосредственно на сайте или это возможно только после того, как кто-то проверяющий выложит все в master ветку на тестовый сайт?

Answer (score 2):

если работаешь в команде - не пуш в мастер, все далай на ветке, надо уметь делать ребейс мастера/ветки,

Comment: думаю, важнее научиться решать конфликты, как минимум

Comment: может есть некий популярный набор команд/действий в team-разработке?

уже понятно, что понадобится опыт rebase и работы с конфликтами

Comment: @lexxl конфликты легко решать через IDE

Comment: @bazJaz типа, в IDE это будет нагляднее?

Comment: @buyboy `rebase`, `cherry-pick`, `squash` (лично делаю через git tortoise), `pull`, `push`, `push -f`

Comment: @buyboy в IDE хорошо видно где конфликт и что надо сделать чтобы его не было
в IDE Intllij IDEA примерно [такой](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/resolveConflict.png) выгляд

Comment: @bazJaz а есть какая-нибудь отдельная приблуда для визуального наблюдения конфликтов?

Comment: @buyboy нет, вы о них узнаете когда будете делать `merge` или в PR будет сообщение

Comment: @bazJaz а это = https://habrahabr.ru/post/150001/

Comment: @buyboy это уже на ваш вкус, но зачем запускать другое приложение для фикса конфликтов если можно сделать уже в открытой IDE

Comment: В моей практике конфликты были крайне редко